# How can I use a Join from another table when im doing a Max to a column in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Getting This issue in which I'm using a Max to a Column, it returns me the number.
(My tables have already the Constraints).

Actual Return

| CVEANO | CVENUMERO | CVEACCION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 7 | 4 |
| 2021 | 1 | 3 |

What I Want to Return from TblACCION

| CVEANO | CVENUMERO | CVEACCION | CVEACCION NAME Brought from tblACCION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 7 | 4 | NAME FOR NUMBER 4 |
| 2021 | 1 | 3 | NAME FOR NUMBER 3 |

My actual Query is

```
 SELECT
*
FROM
    (   
SELECT
    cveano,
    cvenumero,
    max(cveaccion) as ultima
FROM
         tblbitacoragf 
WHERE
    cveusuario = 1
    
GROUP BY
    cvenumero,
    cveano
    order by max(fechaaccion) desc
    )
WHERE ROWNUM <= 4
```

I've tried doing

`INNER JOIN tblACCION ta USING (CVEACCION)`

and in SELECT

`ta.descripcion AS accion`

but I guess there's something wrong, because it always asks me for

> 907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

and I did check for parenthesis, but there's no lack of parenthesis.

**UPDATE**

[I've tried this 2.0 , nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipDEx.png)

Comment: you don't need "as" to alias a table, it is optional to alias a column in the select clause. Replace "tblACCION as ta" with "tblACCION ta".

Comment: I did change it after this post got uploaded (didn't work), but anyway Thnxs :).

Comment: So it's solved ?

Comment: No, it didn't :( .

Comment: Which problem do you have now? As far as syntax is concerned, such a query is OK.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example ? create table statements, a minimal set of data and the failing select ? That would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Sure, but how can I provide it ?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Put everything needed to ask your question in your post. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you are looking for something like this.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      t1.cveano, 
      t1.cvenumero, 
      max(t1.cveaccion) as ultima, 
      max(t2.cveaccionName) as cveaccionName 
    FROM 
      tblbitacoragf t1 
    INNER JOIN tblACCION t2 ON t1.cveaccion = t2.cveaccion 
    WHERE 
      t1.cveusuario = 1 
    GROUP BY 
      t1.cvenumero, 
      t1.cveano 
    order by 
      max(t1.fechaaccion) desc
  ) 
WHERE 
  ROWNUM <= 4
```

Also you can try this.

```
SELECT 
  abc.*, 
  xyz.cveaccionName 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      cveano, 
      cvenumero, 
      max(cveaccion) as ultima 
    FROM 
      tblbitacoragf 
    WHERE 
      cveusuario = 1 
    GROUP BY 
      cvenumero, 
      cveano 
    order by 
      max(fechaaccion) desc
  ) abc 
INNER JOIN tblACCION xyz ON abc.ultima = xyz.cveaccion 
WHERE 
  ROWNUM <= 4
```

Comment: Ohhhh... I get it now, I needed to Max them Both and it worked perfectly, and my join was in Where, needed below From.
Really appreciate it.

Comment: @RudyRosa Yes. You need to use `max` or `min`, if you are using `Group By`. Also `Join` should include after `from`, but before `where`. I have added alternate solution too. You can use what's most appropriate to you.

Comment: Great! Didn't know that could assign a whole parenthesis to an Alias. but correct me if im wrong, abc is alias for the select from tblbitacoragf and xyz from select or join in tblACCION ?
Just trying to get a better understanding at the second solution.

Comment: @RudyRosa Yes, You are correct. **abc** is the subquery `ALIAS`. **xyz** is the `table alias`  of `tblACCION`

Comment: @RudyRosa You can't access all the columns of `tblbitacoragf` table using `abc`. Only the columns and aliases defined in subquery. But, You can access all the columns of `tblACCION` using `xyz.`